# bind svelte elements from {@html} directive

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, svelte, svelte-component

I'm trying to take user input and find all the texts that look something like this
`>>523` like imageboards do. I convert these to HTML template strings through the regex replace method and sanitize the string. then I put the string in to svelte with `{@html input}`. It works very well but I have a few issues.

Here is the link to a REPL
https://svelte.dev/repl/737a125144474234a100cd871c1d4d5b?version=3.42.6

If you look in the console (for some reason it makes me use devtools console, repl console does not work) you can see it gets me the two `a` elements there, but the `forEach` method does not work

I want the created element to link to the referenced post. but one post can have many `quote link` elements in it. and I have no idea how to get a variable reference to them because I can't use `{#each}` and I tried this inside onMount:

```
let quotes = document.getElementsByClassName('postlink');
        quotes.forEach((q) => {
            q.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
                console.log('mousing over q:', q);
            });
            q.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
                console.log('mouse left q:', q);
            });
        });

        console.log(quotes);
```

And it gives me a type error in the console.

**Uncaught TypeError: quotes.forEach is not a function**

How can I accomplish this? I want the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to show a preview of the post the quotelink links to.

Comment: there is a part missing in your code, namely what `quotes` is, can you please add that at least, together with how you the `@html` directive

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example with a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.42.6).

Comment: @StephaneVanraes oh, I clicked edit and the text was there, I added another new line between the formatting and now it shows up. sorry.
I will make repl as soon as I can but its just an html template string

Comment: @johannchopin I have provided a link to REPL in the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassname` returns a NodeList object which doesn't have the forEach function defined, you can parse it to an array like this `[...quotes].forEach`